Facing issue with handling javascript dialog box with playwright
test('Handle Dialogs', async function({ page })
{
    await page.goto("https://testpages.herokuapp.com/styled/alerts/alert-test.html");
    await page.waitForLoadState();

    // alert popup and okay
    const confirmStatus = await page.locator("#alertexamples").isVisible();
    console.log("button status:- ", confirmStatus);
    
    await page.locator("#alertexamples").click();
    page.on("dialog", async (alert) => {
        const text = alert.message();
        console.log("text from alert box:- ", text);
        await alert.accept();
    });
});

Problem is the code is not clicking on the button. I am not getting any error message. I tried to move the click operation below the listener code. But still click operation not performed.
Please advise.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

The click is happening just fine, but you need to set your dialog listener before clicking if you want to see the log that runs in the dialog handler. Otherwise, the dialog will likely fire before the event listener is even set.
The visibility check isn't necessary--.click() already does this as part of its actionability tests.
import {expect, test} from "@playwright/test"; // ^1.46.1

test("Handle Dialogs", async ({page}) => {
  await page.goto(
    "https://testpages.herokuapp.com/styled/alerts/alert-test.html",
    {waitUntil: "commit"}
  );
  page.once("dialog", async alert => {
    console.log(`text from alert box: ${alert.message()}`);
    await alert.accept();
  });
  await page.locator("#alertexamples").click();
});

Output:
$ npx playwright test dialog.test.js

Running 1 test using 1 worker

  ✓  1 dialog.test.js:5:1 › Handle Dialogs (1.0s)
text from alert box: I am an alert box!

  1 passed (1.6s)

I don't think the test is obligated to wait for the dialog callback to run, so if you want to do an assertion, you can promisify the handler:
test("Handle Dialogs", async ({page}) => {
  await page.goto(
    "https://testpages.herokuapp.com/styled/alerts/alert-test.html",
    {waitUntil: "commit"}
  );
  const dialogAccepted = new Promise(resolve =>
    page.once("dialog", async alert => {
      await alert.accept();
      resolve();
    })
  );
  await page.locator("#alertexamples").click();
  await dialogAccepted;
});

See also:

Looking for a Web-First assertion for asserting a dialog's message in TS
Is it possible to write a "isAlertDisplayed" method on a separate AlertHelper file?


Keep in mind : {waitUntil: "commit"}, does not wait for the page to finish loading. https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-page#page-goto-option-wait-until

@VishalAggarwal That's the idea! Locators are used to block for a particular predicate--there's no need to wait for other resources that are irrelevant to the test. Once #alertexamples is on the page, we have everything we need (and nothing we don't). "domcontentloaded" is probably equivalent in this case, but I prefer "commit" since it's potentially faster and less liable to get stuck on a slow resource load.
